# Using $_GET from url parameter to use in getAttribute()

Tags: php

So i'm really confused because i keep getting an error saying its a non object but im unsure if i should be somehow converting it to a object. here's what ive done so far.

```
<?php
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);

$url1 = $_GET['grab'];



function file_get_contents_curl($url){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
}



    $str = $url1;
    $html = file_get_contents_curl($str);
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />' . $html);
        libxml_clear_errors();

$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $hrefValue = $doc->getElementById('uc-download-link')->getAttribute("href"); 

echo $hrefValue;
```

Comment: You will need to trace each variable to make sure they contain what you want them to contain. Is `$html` what you think it is?

Comment: Yeah because when i do it without the $_GET and just place it in ' ' like this $str = 'URL' it works fine but with the $_GET it doesn't

Comment: Have you echo'd out the content of `$_GET` ?

Comment: What @IncredibleHat said. Is `$_GET['grab']` what you think it is?

Comment: This feels like very dangerous code though... throwing anything from the GET var into curl like that and parsing whatever results come out :)

Comment: right i think ive found the issue because the url im trying to put through the $_get has queries in it do you know any solutions to this

Comment: You have to properly apply [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) or [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) like this `echo '<a href="http://www.example.com/?grab='.urlencode( $someUrl ).'">click me</a>';` or `echo '<a href="http://www.example.com/?'.http_build_query( array( 'grab' => $someUrl ) ).'">click me</a>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so instead of posting the entire URL ive just put the ID which is the important park and then reassembled the url in the script

```
<?php
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);

$url1 = $_GET['id'];
$url2 = 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' . $url1;


function file_get_contents_curl($url){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
}



    $str = $url2;
    $html = file_get_contents_curl($str);
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />' . $html);
        libxml_clear_errors();

$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $hrefValue = $doc->getElementById('uc-download-link')->getAttribute("href"); 

echo $hrefValue;
```